# How to mount a public windows 8.1 share in linux

Tags: linux, windows, security, mount, network-shares

I have a folder shared on a windows 8.1 machine. It is shared with "Everyone" and "Everyone" has "read/write" access. In the security tab of the properties dialog of the folder, again "Everyone" has been given "Full Control". I specifically want this folder to be publically accessible to everyone in the office for reading and writing as a scratch/transfer folder, which should include clients visiting the office, so creating a specific user is not an option.

I have a linux machine, as do some others in the office, and I am having problems mounting the shared folder

```
root # mount -t cifs -o guest //Beefy/Scratch /mnt/scratch
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
root #
```

`/var/log/messages` reports

```
May 31 05:12:28 volundr kernel: CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
May 31 05:12:28 volundr kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -113
May 31 05:12:28 volundr kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
May 31 05:12:28 volundr kernel: CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
May 31 05:12:28 volundr kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

I've also tried using `-o sec=ntlm` and various other options (ntlmv2, ntlmv2i, ntlmssp, ntlmsspi), `-o nounix`. If I try with `-o guest,sec=ntlmsspi` I get

```
root # mount.cifs -o guest,sec=ntlmsspi //Beefy/scratch /mnt/scratch
mount error(524): Unknown error 524
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
root #
```

And the accompanying log output in `/var/log/messages`

```
May 31 05:23:45 volundr kernel: CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
May 31 05:23:45 volundr kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -113
May 31 05:23:46 volundr kernel: CIFS VFS: Server does not support signing!
May 31 05:23:46 volundr kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -524
```

Having seen the "Server does not support signing!" message, it occurs to me that something else relevant might be that I have followed the instructions [here](https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html) on my laptop, just because I'm paranoid. However, the results are the same, even when I have commented out these security settings in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and rebooted.

Comment: How could the SSH client settings possibly affect CIFS connections? There isn't a _single_ shared component between them. It's not relevant at all. // Anyway, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17168 might be useful if the system isn't on a domain.

Comment: I thought that maybe the mount.cifs might use openssh for key exchange or something. Hence saying, 'might' in reference to relevance.

Comment: This is a real puzzler. I never had any difficulty with accessing XP shares through Ubuntu/Samba, but 8.1 is another matter. I can mount an 8.1 share using the credentials from a Windows account on the machine, but `mount` always requests a password, and the guest account cannot be used. Whether or not the guest account is enabled, what I can do is to use `nautilus` and type `Ctrl-L` to input a direct path to `smb://192.168.nnn.nnn/Share`: that mounts and connects to my current Ubuntu user. But I have found no way to use `mount` to make it available, unless I create an account for it on 8.1.

Comment: Okay, I can't get it working using guest access. If you turn off 'require passwords' though it works. I can't find any other information though on how this affects access to other resources that aren't shared with the guest user and/or 'everyone'